# Breaking down the SMTP Standard

Tags: email, smtp

The [wikipedia page on SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#SMTP_transport_example) gives a good example of an exchange between Alice and Bob.

Using that as an example, I was curious about some of the specifics of how SMTP works

1. It looks like SMTP is not a file standard, but more of a standard that describes how data is transferred from a sender to a recipient. SMTP-compliant clients can both understand the same "language" (i.e. commands) to transfer data between them. Is that a correct understanding?
2. The `DATA` command describes the data sent. When I receive a message (for example, in GMail) I can view the original email in raw format and it often looks just like that. Is that a standard? Or is just a generally accepted way to format data so that clients can parse them? I'd imagine even something as simple as the date formatting could get messy.
3. The `DATA` section specifies the sender and recpient. Why does this information need to specified again when it was just sent via SMTP in the two previous commands `MAIL FROM:` and `RCPT TO:` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, that is a correct understanding.
2. Yes, there is a standard for that. Check out [rfc5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322).
3. The `From`, `To`, and `Cc` headers in the raw message text do not have to match the addresses specified in the `MAIL FROM` and `RCPT TO` commands. The message headers also contain more information than what is passed to `MAIL FROM` and `RCPT TO` such as the recipient names.

For more information about the SMTP protocol, you could read [rfc5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321).